# What happens to a SharePoint Designer workflow when I delete the item it is running on?

Tags: 2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow on a document library I created in SharePoint Designer 2007.  The workflow will pause for a long period, perhaps 90 days or more).

What happens to the workflow if the document is deleted in the mean time?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow is stopped, as it is a specific instance tied to that item.

Comment: Not a good enough question to earn an upvote?  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/

Comment: Just because you get an answer doesn't mean the person answering it views it as a quality question, its subjective and personal.  I assumed it relatively easy to find the answer so you didn't get a vote.  I have spent some time and have had trouble getting back information that I would reasonable expect someone to determine the answer from without further searching the content returned, so you get the up vote now.  If, in the question it mentioned what you did to try and find the answer, I would have been inclined to vote for it earlier.

Comment: I did look, and it difficult to format a question with such common words.  I wanted an answer, not an additional hour to my searching.  Thanks for you answer, I removed the accepted check because you did not qualify your claim or cite a source.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is actually the answer. In SharePoint 2013 I create an item that starts a workflow that immediately pauses for 5 minutes, then sends an email. If I delete the item before the 5 minute pause completes, the workflow still wakes up and sends a blank email. Bizarre...